# Creation of simple CRUD website using Python which framework?

Tags: python

I need to create a simple python website showing customer by salesman and sales by customer. No update of data at all at this time.  Which framework might be best.  I am not a web guru by any means can read HTML, and Understand CSS.  Data is in MySQL.  This is a quick and dirty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is your best bet as it has a simple ORM and an [automatic admin interface](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) which might prove useful. You might be able to simple "switch off" the ability to update records in the admin interface and just use that.

Comment: +1: CRUD is free with Django.  Create the model and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is really an opinion question. My personal preference is for Django. If you already have a database, you can auto-generate models for the data, assuming all your tables have primary keys and aren't too "weird". The admin application will quickly give you the ability to view and modify all of your data.

http://www.djangoproject.com/